# Input for field is missing even after i type the correct format on the API

Tags: django

I have coded the following:

models.py

```
class Job(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    combinedparameters = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
```

serializers.py

```
class JobSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ['combinedparameters']
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_job(request):
    job = Job()
    jobserializer = JobSerializers(job, data = request.data)
    if jobserializer.is_valid():
        jobserializer.save()
        return Response(jobserializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(jobserializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Page looks like this:
[image: ![image|690x331](upload://nKUSSPmRI0IUrUcKWa9naYdRk4B.png)]

But if i copy

```
{'device': 177, 'configuration': {'port_range': 'TenGigabitEthernet1/0/1,TenGigabitEthernet1/0/2,TenGigabitEthernet1/0/3,TenGigabitEthernet1/0/4,TenGigabitEthernet1/0/5', 'port_mode': 'Access', 'port_status': 'Disabled', 'port_param1': 'Test\\n1\\n2\\n3', 'port_param2': 'Test\\n1\\n2\\n3'}}
```

And click post, got error saying the single quotes have to be double quotes. So i changed it to :

```
{"device": 177, "configuration": {"port_range": "TenGigabitEthernet1/0/1,TenGigabitEthernet1/0/5", "port_mode": "Access", "port_status": "Disabled", "port_param1": "1\\n2\\n3", "port_param2": "1\\n2\\n3"}}
```

I clicked post again and this time the following error comes out:
[image]

I dont understand why is it happening. The reason why I key in the long format because this is the format i want to save in my database and this format is created upon saving from my html that creates the job

Postman:

[image]

Updated Postman:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post data object does not contain the required key "combinedparameters".  I'm guessing that big object you copy into content is the string you want saved into the CharField combinedparameters?  If that's the case you should structure your post data like this:

```
{
    "combinedparameters": "{'device': 177, 'configuration': {'port_range': 'TenGigabitEthernet1/0/1,TenGigabitEthernet1/0/2,TenGigabitEthernet1/0/3,TenGigabitEthernet1/0/4,TenGigabitEthernet1/0/5', 'port_mode': 'Access', 'port_status': 'Disabled', 'port_param1': 'Test\\n1\\n2\\n3', 'port_param2': 'Test\\n1\\n2\\n3'}}"
}
```

Comment: It actually worked, may I ask how come though? I thought it was just typing in the format I want in the content as ```combinedparameters``` is declared in serializers.py so i assume the page already knows that the content box is for ```combinedparameters```? I also tried using Postman for this but it doesnt work. I updated the post with the screenshot of Postman, would you mind taking a look at it and advise me why? Under the value, I copied the same thing you suggested

Comment: The content input is a request body that will be sent to the endpoint of the current page you are on.  So you have to provide key and value pairs so it knows what field you are trying to save a value to.  Your Postman request is not working because you are trying to put the data in the request headers, the data needs to go in the request body (click on the body tab and then select json).  Then you will be apple to send the same thing that you sent in the content input

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. But I have another question. Isnt this Django API framework and postman the same on how it work? I managed to send a POST request with the double quotes format. But I am not allowed in the browser? I updated the post with the screenshot from Postman